# Need a Sound Engine or Audio Engine for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

I want to play multiple tracks simuntanusly and mix them. Apply effects like flange, reverb, chorus any one know a sound engine working on iphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard about fmod?
Take a look at [this website](http://www.fmod.org/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at The Amazing Audio Engine: http://theamazingaudioengine.com/

Answer (score 4):

Check out [Superpowered](http://superpowered.com). Looks pretty powerful.

Comment: Hi..Could yot tell me how to save teh output file to docuemtn directory from Superpowered

Comment: @Bharathi, have you ever found this? I am looking to save audio output to a file?

Comment: Hi.. Yes I done my own algorithm to save the output file..We need to use the default iOS codes to get the out put

Answer (score 1):

OpenAL is pretty powerful. It can take multiple sources (upto 32 i believe) and play them at the same time. Check this [link](http://benbritten.com/blog/2008/11/06/openal-sound-on-the-iphone/) out. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

BASS audio library also has an [iOS](http://www.un4seen.com/forum/?topic=10910) version with a shareware license that costs 125€.

Answer (score 1):

Also there is this very nice cross platform Audio API for iOS and Android called `Cricket Audio`. You can refer to it from the below link:

[Cricket Audio API for Games and Other apps](http://www.crickettechnology.com)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to take a look at [Novocaine](https://github.com/alexbw/novocaine), which is really straightforward to use.

Answer (score 0):

[fmod.org](http://fmod.org) provide a nice framework that helps a lot while working with audio.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using something like Cocos2D Simple Audio Engine:[SoundMaster engine](https://github.com/jerminal/SoundMaster).
But it has better memory management, cross-fade effects and other features.